# Looking for a BASIC decruncher: inserting spaces between keywords

Tags: basic

Many dialects of 8-bit BASIC allow ‘crunched’ source; that is, most spaces can be ignored between keywords:

```
10 FORX=1TO10
20 PRINTX,X^2
30 NEXTX
```

After Microsoft BASIC-80 Rev. 5.x, however, spaces were required:

```
10 FOR X=1 TO 10
20 PRINT X,X^2
30 NEXT X
```

Other later BASIC interpreters (such as Locomotive BASIC on the Amstrad CPC) required spaces, while others didn't (for example BBC BASIC).

I'm looking for a program (Linux-capable preferred) that will reliably insert the necessary spaces into BASIC text. I'm not looking for the ability to detokenize: assume I have the text available.

Comment: So is this about converting sources? Do you got any specific BASIC in mind? After all, this depends much on the keywords valid. Can it be assumed, that it's correct BASIC code, so no ambiguities?  If yes, some Perl regex may doe it.

Comment: Let's assume that the code is valid. Minimum target would be PET BASIC 4, though MSX BASIC would be ideal.

Comment: Assuming valid code does help, except it would still depends much on the vocabulary. `10 LETA=NOTA` would already give a headache in PET-BASIC - or worse, `10 A=BMODC` which in PET BASIC would have to stay like that, while as MSX it needs to be turned into `10 A = B MOD C`. I guess it would need to be a tool tuned to a certain dialect and work according to this dialects keyword list. Not to mention the classic `GO TO` vs. `GOTO` (Oh, and no, I do not know any existing generic tool. I'd just sit down and sketch up a bunch of Perl)

Comment: It seems that it'd be easier to write a pretty-printer if you did have the tokenized form rather than the text; the lexing has all been done for you.

Comment: but I *don't* have the tokens, @another-dave … I wouldn't have this issue if I did

Comment: The only universal and sure way is to parse (or "tokenize") the source code and re-create it back. Tokenizing is not difficult, but you need a set of all keywords (statements, functions, ...) and implement some syntax specific (e.g. "implicit LET"). So I really doubt there is any "universal" decruncher. I wouldn't do it the regexp way, a simple stream tokenizer (based on FSM) should be better for it.

Comment: I'm trying to solve just that problem myself - Super Star Trek was originally published in crunched form.

Comment: To be clear, a parser for this case would not be spectacularly difficult. It's a far cry from a effective, albeit crude BASIC pretty printer and a full boat fully syntax aware parser. BASIC statements are pretty simple, with FOR and IF statements probably being the most "difficult". Especially if you're dealing with already correct BASIC, so you can make all sorts of assumptions.

Answer (score 7):

Here's something that should do the trick.

It's written in AWK. Any language I picked will be the wrong language. awk (or gawk) is everywhere.

Copy and paste it into a file (say, expand.awk).

```
awk -f expand.awk crunched.bas > uncrunched.bas
```

The script:

```
# License: Creative Commons 0 https://creativecommons.org/share-your-work/public-domain/cc0/
# Assumes all uppercase, and inability to embed quotes in quoted strings.
# Basic philosophy is to break out the quoted strings, and then process
# the individual statements separated by colons. Then put it all back
# together again.
BEGIN {
    # list of keywords, EXCEPT for 'TO', it's handled special
    keywords="OPEN:CLOSE:CLEAR:INPUT:IF:THEN:ELSE:FOR:NEXT:GOTO:GOSUB:LINE:READ:DEF:DIM:PRINT";
    split(keywords, keylist, ":");
}

{
    # split out the quoted strings. They will be even fields when done.
    split($0, a, "\"");
    for(i = 1; i <= length(a); i++) {
        if (i % 2 == 0) {
            # quoted string, skip it
            continue;
        }
        # expand this chunk of the line
        a[i] = expand_line(a[i]);
    }

    # rebuild the line
    line = "";
    for(i = 1; i <= length(a); i++) {
        p = a[i]
        if (i % 2 == 0) {
            # quoted string, add the quotes back
            p = "\"" p "\"";
        }
        line = line p;
    }
    # clean up PRINT" and INPUT"
    # if these happen to be in quoted strings, kind of out of luck.
    gsub("PRINT\"", "PRINT \"", line);
    gsub("INPUT\"", "INPUT \"", line);

    # out it goes
    print line;
}

function expand_line(line, i, k, l) {
    # break up in to statements
    split(line, statements, ":");
    for(i = 1; i <= length(statements); i++) {
        # expand the keywords for each statement
        for(k = 1; k <= length(keylist); k++) {
            statements[i] = expand(statements[i], keylist[k]);
        }
        # because of GOTO, TO (of FOR TO NEXT) is handled special
        statements[i] = expand_to(statements[i]);
    }
    # rejoin with the :
    line = statements[1];
    l = length(statements);
    if (l == 1) {
        return line;
    }
    for(i = 2; i <= l; i++) {
        line = line ":" statements[i];
    }
    return line;
}


function expand(line, keyword) {
    # for each key word, check for space at each end
    rx=keyword "[^ ]";
    if (match(line, rx) > 0) {
        gsub(keyword, keyword " ", line);
    }
    rx="[^ ]" keyword;
    if (match(line, rx) > 0) {
        gsub(keyword, " " keyword, line);
    }

    return line;
}

function expand_to(line) {
    # hide any GOTOs
    gsub("GOTO", "xxx", line);

    # fix the TO
    if(match(line, "TO[^ ]") > 0) {
        gsub("TO", "TO ", line);
    }
    if(match(line, "[^ ]TO") > 0) {
        gsub("TO", " TO", line);
    }

    # put the GOTOs back
    gsub("xxx", "GOTO", line);
    return line;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for that. Good parser. It really has trouble with `RESTORE`, unsurprisingly

Answer (score 6):

If you're happy with a .net core solution you could take my MS Basic clone, load the code and then save it again.

https://github.com/peteri/ClassicBasic

You would need to remove the EditLine function in the GlassTeletype which uses Win32 interop to provide an line editor (invoked by edit nnnn where nnnn is the linenumber) and maybe give it a little tweak to get rid of the BOM when it saves.

Comment: I tried to build this under Mono the other week with no success. I don't see any way that this will work for me, sorry

Comment: Ah that's possibly because it's a netcoreapp 2.0. If I get a chance I'll give it a try at running on Linux over the weekend because there's very little OS specific in there. Do you actually need mono or would dotnet core be okay?

Comment: I have just got dotnet core running, but you'll have to ELI5 the build process

Comment: Okay I'll setup dotnet core on Linux at home (I don't think my home PC is currently setup) this evening and get back to you.

Comment: Added instructions for ubuntu and dotnet core 3.1. in readme.md on this branch https://github.com/peteri/ClassicBasic/tree/UpgradeToCore3.1 however I've only tested in a WSL container.

Comment: thank you. That built fine. And it does add spaces, too. Nice collection of games that come with it, too

Answer (score 1):

Applesoft BASIC appears to not care about whitespace, but it gets a little weird with `AT`/`ATN`/`TO`.  For example, you can write `A TO X AT O`, but if you crunch the whitespace out it will instead be parsed as `A TO XA TO`.  For everything else, whitespace is ignored.  `ON ERR GO TO` becomes `ONERR GOTO`.  The trick when scanning is to find the longest match (`ON` is also a valid keyword).

I don't know how various dialects of BASIC compare in this respect.  Just be aware that not everything that appears to ignore whitespace actually does.

I've written code that converts a text file with an Applesoft BASIC program to tokenized form, as well as code that converts the tokenized program to text.  They're built into [CiderPress](http://a2ciderpress.com).  You can find the C++ source for the parser [here](https://github.com/fadden/ciderpress/blob/master/app/BasicImport.cpp), and the pretty-printer [here](https://github.com/fadden/ciderpress/blob/master/reformat/BASIC.cpp).  If your sources were in Applesoft you could launder them quite easily.  For anything else some coding will be required.

(There's a comment in the parsing code with a chunk of the 6502 code from Applesoft, so you can see how it actually parses `AT`/`ATN`/`TO`.)

Comment: They're not in Applesoft, but thanks. CiderPress is a great tool and deals with Applesoft BASIC's quirk rather well.

Comment: @scruss: I figured it might work if the code in question used a subset of Applesoft, e.g. your trivial example worked fine. I don't know enough about the BASIC you're targeting to tell where it'll break down, or how much work would be required to adapt the existing code (e.g. swapping out elements of the token table could be straightforward).